# Modification of a Vector based on elements sequence

Tags: r, vector, transformation

How is it possible to transform the following vector:

```
x <- c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 3, 2, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 8)
```

into the desired form:

```
y <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 2, 5, 5, 5, 5, 8, 8, 8, 8)
```

Any idea would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's another approach using only base R:

```
idx <- x != 0
split(x, cumsum(idx) - idx) <- x[idx]
```

The x-vector is now:

```
x
#[1] 1 1 1 1 3 3 2 5 5 5 5 8 8 8 8
```

Comment: fantastic solution!

Answer (score 3):

you can use `zoo` to fill NAs via `na.locf` function as follows,

```
zoo::na.locf(replace(x, x==0, NA), fromLast = TRUE)
#[1] 1 1 1 1 3 3 2 5 5 5 5 8 8 8 8
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `rle`, you can do the following in base R.

```
tmp <- rle(x)
tmp$values[which(tmp$values == 0)] <- tmp$values[which(tmp$values == 0) + 1L]

inverse.rle(tmp)
 [1] 1 1 1 1 3 3 2 5 5 5 5 8 8 8 8
```

Note that this assumes the final value is not 0. If this is not the case, you could use `head(which(tmp$values == 0), -1)` in place of `which(tmp$values == 0)` to drop the final value.